# How to solve ERROR system error 24 using Rstudio-Server?

Tags: r, rstudio, rstudio-server

I have an error, where I cant find anything related to it on the `www`:
The error pops up everythime I start/login into Rstudio-Server(installed on an Linux-Server). It worked for month.

```
  05 Jan 2016 07:13:38 [rsession-me] ERROR system error 24 (Too many open     files); OCCURRED AT: core::system::file_monitor::Handle      core::system::file_monitor::detail::registerMonitor(const core::FilePath&,      bool, const boost::function<bool(const core::FileInfo&)>&, const       core::system::file_monitor::Callbacks&) /home/ubuntu/rstudio/src/cpp/core/system       /file_monitor/LinuxFileMonitor.cpp:455; LOGGED FROM: void        session::module_context::<unnamed>::onMonitoringError(const       core::Error&) /home/ubuntu/rstudio/src/cpp/session/SessionModuleContext.cpp:360
```

I tried:

`sudo rstudio-server suspend-all`

`sudo rstudio-server stop`

`sudo rstudio-server restart`

But the error still pops up.

Comment: I remember something like this in rare cases when I closed a specific program "in the wrong way". The only thing that worked for me was restarting the machine... After a few month it occurred again. But a restart solves the problem in general.

Comment: Have you tried just restarting the RStudio server ?  A machine reboot may not be needed.

Comment: Also by searching "too many open files" on the internet you get some good description of the problem... Looks like it is a general problem and not just rstudio related.

Comment: @ drmariod. I would like to avoid to restart the linux-machine. there are plenty of jobs running. But I feel I have to :).  @ steveb yes, i restarted the server.